# Is it possible to access and create external G Suite domain contacts using People API?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts, google-people-api

I know it's possible to do it with Google [Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts). What about People API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Domain shared contacts can only be created with the  Domain Shared Contacts API or with the App [New Shared Contacts Service](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/new_shared_contacts/837377049623).

The People API allows the access to G Suite domain profile data - if [external contact and profile sharing is enabled](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6343701), but it is not meant for creation of shared contacts.